# Can I transfer my TensorFlow Python environment from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda

I have Linux Mint dual booted on my system, and I recently set up Anaconda on it. Essentially, I want to copy/paste the tensorflow environment I created with all the packages I've installed from my Windows 10 platform to my Mint platform. Will I be able to simply create a .zip file of the Windows tensorflow environment, transfer it to a USB drive, and copy/paste it into my Anaconda environments folder in Mint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Tensorflow contains many shared libraries next to Python code.
Shared libraries are not portable between operating systems.

Instead, use the `conda` tool on your Ubuntu installation to check which packages are installed. (Use [`conda list`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-list.html).) Do the same on your windows install. Then install any missing packages in your windows installation.